# Django get urlpatterns regex by view name

Tags: python, django, url

I am not looking for `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse`
what I want to do is :
I have a urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('xxx.views',
    url(r'^search/$', 'resume_search', name='xxx_resume_search'),
    url(r'^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', 'recruit_manage', name='xxx_recruit_manage'),
)
```

I want to do something like

```
rr = reverse_regex('xxx_recruit_manage')
```

`rr` would be `'^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$'`

if

```
urlpatterns = patterns('xxx.views',
    url(r'^search/$', 'resume_search', name='xxx_resume_search'),
    url(r'^recruit/manage/$', 'recruit_manage', name='xxx_recruit_manage'),
)
    url(r'^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', 'recruit_manage', name='xxx_recruit_manage'),
)
```

`rr` would be `['^recruit/manage/$','^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']`

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `urls.py` is like any other module where you can import it and see what things it has.

The below is quite crude but works and shows off the API.

```
import myapp.urls as my_urls

regex_pattern = my_urls.urlpatterns[2].regex.pattern
>> ^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)
```

a bit better

```
regex_object = filter(lambda x:'xxx_recruit_manage' == x.name, my_urls.urlpatterns)
>> [<RegexURLPattern recruit_manage ^recruit/manage/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$>]
```

Comment: Wonderful!Thank you.`'xxx_recruit_manage' == x.name` is better, `in` may result to match a url name contain `'xxx_recruit_manage'`, such as  `'xxx_recruit_manage_list'`.

Comment: Yes, of course, updated the answer to reflect that :) Just remember that you have two `name` with the same name.